# Distribution of sample variance

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, variance

I have a problem and I am really not sure how to process it.

> We have 10 samples of 25 variables X~N(50,25). How many of these
>   samples will have a variance of maximum 101?

$W = \frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}$ ~ $\chi^2$ with (n-1) degrees of liberty.
$$P(S^2 \leq b)$$
$$P( W \leq \frac{(n-1)b}{\sigma^2} ) $$

Are my first steps correct? At this point, I don't know what to do. Also, in the equations, i'm not sure which $n$ to take and what is $b$.

Thank you.

Comment: $n $ is the size of the sample whose variance is under consideration, so 25 here. $b $ is the upper bound requested for the sample variance, so 101 here. The rest is for software or tables.

Comment: ok I see thank you. so the fact that there is 10 samples doesn't affect anything?

Comment: Well, it doesn't affect the probability of the inequality in a given sample, but it comes up when you are asked to predict the number of samples in which the inequality holds (which should be roughly 10 times the probability).

Comment: @Ian I'm not sure how to continue after putting in $n$ and $b$. Is it ok that i get $ 1 - P(W \gt 49.49) $ ? And I'm not sure how to use this table https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m170/tbl-chi.html

Comment: Go to the row with 24 degrees of freedom, then $P(W>49.49)$ is approximately given by the probability value at the top in the column whose entry is closest to $49.49$. So in this case the table would suggest 0.005, though the actual answer is a fair bit less, since your number is a fair bit larger than their number.